# Cannot convert from '(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)' to 'Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that will create a new cube named "spawnee" in a random location and have a pre-set rotation named "spawnPos.rotation":

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public Transform spawnPos;
    public GameObject spawnee;
    Vector3 a;
    Vector3 b;
    Vector3 c;
    void Update() {
        Instantiate(spawnee, (a,b,c), spawnPos.rotation);
        }
    }
```

But when I save it and return to Unity, it gives me an error: Cannot convert from '(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)' to 'Vector3'. Is there a problem in my code?

Answer (score 2):

In [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) fuction, the second parameter is Vector3

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
```

Please use this

```
 float a,b,c;//your randome position axis in seperate variables
 Instantiate(spawnee, new Vector(a,b,c), spawnPos.rotation);
```

Or this

```
Vector3 yourRandomPosition;
Instantiate(spawnee, yourRandomPosition, spawnPos.rotation);
```

Comment: `Vector` has to be `Vector3` ;)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thanks for update

Comment: Also note that you made a, b and c Vector3 themselves. They should just be doubles or ints.